# Richfaces 4.0.0.FINAL Skinning standard JSF tags and Html tags automatically cannot load

Tags: spring, jsf-2, richfaces, spring-webflow, myfaces

I've enabled skinning in my web.xml but nothing seems to take effect in my richfaces 4.0.0.FINAL why? My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<!-- Log4j configurated in spring!!!, 
before any code directly calling log4j (calling through commons logging doesn't count)? Jing Xue -->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j-webapp.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>1000</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>myWebapp-instance-root</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


<display-name>richfaces-application</display-name>
<!-- Listener para crear el Spring Container compartido por todos los 
Servlets y Filters (WebApplication Context)-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    classpath*:META-INF/spring/spring-master.xml
    WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
<!-- For JSF -->
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
<!-- Jboss not use it bundle integrated JSF -->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

<!-- Facelets, tell JSF to use Facelets -->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
    </context-param>

<!-- Spring JavaServiceFaces framework ApacheMyfaces --> 
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<!-- Spring Security, for all -->
    <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

<!-- RichFaces Framework -->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinningClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
    </context-param>

<!-- Servlets for JSF-->
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!-- Servlet for Dispatcher of flows -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>transportes</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/transportes-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup> 
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>transportes</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/flows/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Servlet register for SpringFaces, SpringJavaScript -->
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!-- Page That control SpringWeb -->
    <!--  
    <error-page>
       <error-code>404</error-code>
       <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    -->
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/flows/inscripcion/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

and the page that i was to inject my blueSky theme. login.xhtml

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/flows/template/default.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

 <ui:define name="windowTitle">
    #{msgs.loginTitle}
 </ui:define>

 <ui:define name="heading">
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/flows/sections/login/header.xhtml"/>
 </ui:define>

 <ui:define name="sidebarLeft">
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/flows/sections/login/sidebarLeft.xhtml"/>
 </ui:define>

 <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>
       <h:panelGrid columns="2">
      #{msgs.namePrompt}
      <h:inputText id="name" value="#{user.name}"/>
      #{msgs.passwordPrompt}
      <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user.password}"/>
       </h:panelGrid>
       <p>
      <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.loginButtonText}"
                       action="planetarium"/>
       </p>
    </h:form>
 </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

this is my template.xhtml

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <title><ui:insert name="windowTitle"/></title>
   </h:head>

   <h:body>   
      <div id="heading" >
     <ui:insert name="heading">
        <ui:include src="/sections/inscripcion/header.xhtml"/>
     </ui:insert>
      </div>

      <div id="sidebarLeft"  style="float:left;height : 193px; width : 101px;">
     <ui:insert name="sidebarLeft">
        <ui:include src="/sections/inscripcion/sidebarLeft.xhtml"/>
     </ui:insert>
      </div>    

      <div id="content"  style="float:right;height : 193px; width : 689px;">
     <ui:insert name="content"/>
      </div>
      <!--  <ui:debug/>-->
   </h:body>
</html>
```

Why not load the blueSky skin?

Comment: To exclude one and other, do you have a `<h:head>` in `default.xhtml`? If so, what do you see in the generated HTML `<head>` element when you open page in browser and do *View Source*?

Comment: <head> 
      <title> 
    Integral System Goods Vehicle Registration</title><link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/projvehimerc/rfRes/skinning.ecss.xhtml?db=eAHL6rC8BQAEkAIG" /></head>

Comment: So, you don't have an `<h:head>` at all?

Comment: yes, I edit my post with the code of template.xhtml